# ejb ref resolution error for remote business interface - Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to implement an EJB module but when the client application tries to retrieve the interface object I am getting an error. The client app has the same interface files than the EJB module but in its respective local package. I think that the error is at the server side. I replicated the example from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm) but using a glassfish server; the simple EJB explained in the tutorial works fine, but when I try to apply the same theory to implement a more complex EJB it does not work. Surely I am doing something wrong but there is not much information about this error and I am really lost.

**This is the error from the client application**

```
    javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/ManagementUtils/UsuarioService' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at com.management.test.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote]
        at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:433)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:75)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.getBusinessIntfClassLoader(EJBUtils.java:685)
        at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.loadGeneratedRemoteBusinessClasses(EJBUtils.java:462)
        at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:413)
        ... 7 more
```

**This is the EJB `UsuarioService` in the EJB module:**

```
package com.management.persistence.service;

import com.management.persistence.interfaces.service.UsuarioServiceRemote;
import com.management.persistence.dao.UsuarioDao;
import com.management.persistence.model.Usuario;
import com.management.persistence.facades.ServiceFacade;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Stateless
@Remote(UsuarioServiceRemote.class)
public class UsuarioService extends ServiceFacade implements UsuarioServiceRemote {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuariosDao;

    public UsuarioService() {
    }

    public UsuarioService(UsuarioDao usuariosDao) {
        super(usuariosDao);
        this.usuariosDao = usuariosDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UsuarioDao getUsuariosDao() {
        return usuariosDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario findByUsuarioAndContrasena(String login, String contrasena) {
        validateSession();
        Usuario usuario = usuariosDao.findByUsuarioAndContrasena(login, contrasena);
        closeCurrentSession();
        return usuario;
    }

}
```

**This is the interface `UsuarioServiceRemote` in the EJB Module:**

```
package com.management.persistence.interfaces.service;

import com.management.persistence.interfaces.ServiceFacadeRemote;
import com.management.persistence.interfaces.dao.UsuarioDaoRemote;
import com.management.persistence.model.Usuario;


public interface UsuarioServiceRemote extends ServiceFacadeRemote {

    public UsuarioDaoRemote getUsuariosDao();

    public Usuario findByUsuarioAndContrasena(String login, String contrasena);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The client app has the same interface files than the EJB module but in its respective local package"? The `UsuarioServiceRemote` interface used by the client must be identical with that used by the server, including its package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @SteveC yes, in effect, my error was the package name, it was different in the client app than in the server, so in the client app I renamed the package of the business interface and also the same for the entity class, after that everything works well.